# CSS - As page zooms out, font size increases

Tags: html, css

I have a pair of buttons, that are joined by `inline-block` and `float`. They are scaled correctly until zooming out on Google Chrome to about 67%. Then it seems that the font becomes larger than the actual buttons.

How the buttons should look:
[image: Normal Functionality]

This is how it looks afterwards:
[image: Broken Functionality]

I believe that due to the scale of the font size, it is breaking the layout of the buttons also. Here is the CSS that relates to the buttons.

```
.btn { 
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.688em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  line-height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.btn-facebook {
  background: url('../img/buttons/facebook.png') repeat-x;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.btn.btn-twitter {
  background: url('../img/buttons/twitter.png') repeat-x;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.btn.btn-orange {
  background: url(../img/buttons/orange.png) repeat-x;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus {
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.btn-facebook i,
.btn.btn-twitter i {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#facebook" title="Sign Up With Facebook" class="btn btn-facebook">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign up with Facebook
</a>
<a href="#twitter" title="Sign Up With Twitter" class="btn btn-twitter">
   <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Sign up with Twitter
</a>
```

It's a little confusing as I've never had this problem before. I thought that it could be something to do with me using PX? I tried changing my values to EM however, nothing seemed to happen.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap? If so, it applies @media queries at certain screen breakpoints to most of its elements (including .btn) that change font-size.

Comment: @SamuelMS Yeah, I am using Twitter Bootstrap. Should I try renaming my classes to avoid this issue?

Comment: If you want to use Bootstrap button styles, no. You can, however, add your own @media queries to override Bootstrap's font-size styling. https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Comment: Thank you, I tried this also but no such luck. Please see my updated question for a jSFiddle

Comment: Can you try adding "font-size: 14px !important;" to your btn-Facebook and btn-twitter class styles?

Comment: Still the same issue! It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You might need javascript to complete what you want.

Comment: Hmm, I'd rather keep this to CSS, there has to be some way other than creating a JS hack.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `line-height` and use `padding` instead for the buttons.

Comment: I have done so. But I don't think this relates to the issue that I'm having?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle and I will check it out and update the answer accordingly